# What is the formal definition of a symmetry of a subset of the real plane?

Tags: symmetry

Consider a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. What does it mean for a function $f$ to be a symmetry of $S$? After all, there are usually infinitely many bijections on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that send $S$ to $S$. I would very much like some clarification of this topic.

Comment: Have you not given the answer yourself? A symmetry (yes, not *the* symmetry) is a bijection $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f(S) = S$.

Comment: How many symmetries are there for an equilateral triangle? How about a square or some other n-gon? There may be infinitely many bijections but the symmetries have invariants. I recommend you do a Google search for symmetries of the plane. They have been studied extensively and classified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing ingredient is that you want $f$ to preserve distances: if $d(x,y)$ is the distance between point $x$ and $y$, then you want $$d(x,y) =d(f(x),f(y))$$ for all points $x$ and $y$.

A function with this property is called an *isometry*.  When we speak of geometric symmetries, we always require them to be isometries. It can be shown that any isometry of the plane is a reflection, a rotation, a translation, or a composition of these.